# How to put different objects in a List

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a web page where a user can drag and drop certain widgets into a single placeholder. Each widget has its own set of properties.

For example, suppose I have the following HTML widgets:

```
Widget1:
 - Title field
 - Technical name field
```

And another widget that is more dynamic:

```
Widget2:
 - Range picker field 1 (0 to 100)
 - Range picker field 2 (0 to 100)
               ------------------
               | (+) Add picker |
               ------------------
 (can add as many range pickers as needed)
```

Now with the click of a button these settings are saved to the database. But at some point I also need to read that data from it again.

For example, suppose I have the following classes for the Widgets:

```
interface IWidget { }

class Widget1 : IWidget
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string TechnicalName {get;set;}
}

class Widget2 : IWidget
{
    public List<int> PickerValues {get;set;}
}
```

Then store that in a `List`.

```
var widgets = new List<IWidget>();
widgets.Add(new Widget1());
widgets.Add(new Widget2());
```

That would work. But then getting an object from that list again is a problem:

```
var widget = widgets.First();
widget.?????   // <-- NO INTELLISENSE!
```

That means it doesn't know what actual implementation it has. I'd have to cast it. But how, if I don't know what widgets are stored in there? It can be a list of 1, 5 or even 10 different widgets in any order.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Just as a side note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552677/are-empty-interfaces-code-smell

Comment: The point of creating an abstraction with an interface is that *you shouldn't care* about the concrete implementation. Currently, your interface is meaningless. What do you want to do with those widgets?

Comment: What do you want to do with the IWidget once you pull it out of the list?

Comment: you can see about [as](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/cscsdfbt.aspx) and [is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/scekt9xw.aspx) keywords

Comment: `IWidget` doesn't define any members, so you won't get any intellisense. You need to place common functionality in the interface, otherwise yes, you will have to cast.

Comment: Why you need to cast? what operation do you expect to do after retrieve the widget? If its a common behaviour to all widgets, it should be a method of the interface and each widget implements its specific behaviour

Comment: With an empty interface, you may as well have a `List<object>`, because you will have to check the type of each item and then cast in order to get intellisense...

Answer (score 1):

You currently have a list of objects that all implement the `IWidget` interface. Accessing them directly will only give you intellisense on the properties of `IWidget` (which has none).

In order to resolve this, you either need to put some properties in the `IWidget` interface, or check the type of each item and then cast it, like:

```
IWidget widget = widgets.First();

var widget1 = widget as Widget1;

if (widget1 != null)
{
    widget1.TechnicalName = "new name"; // <-- We have intellisense
}
```

You could also have some logic that checks each widget in a loop, like:

```
foreach (var widget in widgets)
{
    if (widget is Widget1)
    {
        var widget1 = (Widget1) widget;
        // Do something with Widget1 types here
    }
    else if (widget is Widget2)
    {
        var widget2 = (Widget2)widget;
        // Do something with Widget2 types here
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could just get the first Widget1 (or Widget2) from the list by doing something like:

```
Widget1 widget = widgets.OfType<Widget1>().First();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Polymorphism to address your issue:

```
interface IWidget 
{
    public void readData();
}

class Widget1 : IWidget
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TechnicalName { get; set; }

    public void readData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("- Title: {0}\n- Technical name: {1}", Title, TechnicalName);
    }
}

class Widget2 : IWidget
{
    public List<int> PickerValues { get; set; }

    public void readData()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i <= PickerValues.Count; i++)
        {
            builder.AppendLine(String.Format("- Range picker field {0}: {1}",i,PickerValues[i-1]));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

And Later on...

```
        var widgets = new List<IWidget>();
        widgets.Add(new Widget1());
        widgets.Add(new Widget2());
        var widget = widgets.First();
        widget.readData(); // will print correct output for each type of widget, as implemented on each widget.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your choice is to type-check the instance first:

```
var widget = widgets.First();
if (widget is Widget1)
{
    var widget1 = (Widget1) widget;
    widget1.DoSomethingSpecificToWidget1();
}
```

Alternatively, with additional LinQ functionality, you can easily split your list to genric sub-lists. This will work well if you do not need to process the widgets in the order they are stored in the `widgets` variable.

```
var w1List = widgets.OfType<Widget1>();// you may also call `.ToList()`
var w2List = widgets.OfType<Widget2>();

foreach (var w1 in w1List)
{
    w1.DoSomethingSpecificToWidget1(); // w1 is now Widget1
}
```