# Using Empty Interfaces

Tags: c#, linq, interface

I've read a number of articles including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552677/are-empty-interfaces-code-smell) on the subject of Empty or 'marker' interfaces. I have concluded that I cannot use custom attributes in my case as I need to be able to include the instance of a class to another method and, as these classes have nothing in common, I have no option but to use a 'marker' interface.

As an example, I might have

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Bar
{
    public Guid Identifier {get;set;}
    public DateTime DueDate {get;set;}
}
```

and I need to pass them to a method in another class and because there may be many different types that need to be passed to the method, I've defined it like this...

```
public void MyMethod(IMyInterface model)
{
    // Do something clever here
}
```

And All I've had to do to make this work is to 'implement' `IMyInterface` on `Foo` and `Bar`.

So to the question. I now find I need to call my `MyMethod()` method with an anonymous type created from a LINQ statement, so I tried this ...

```
var data = <Some Complex LINQ>.Select(a=> new { AString = a.Value1, ADecimal = a.Value2});
MyClass.MyMethod(data);
```

Sadly, I get the following compile-time error:

> Error 202 Cannot convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to
>   'IMyInterface' via a reference
>   conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping
>   conversion, or null type conversion

Now, I know I *could* create a local class and use that in the same way as I have my *standard* classes, but my requirements mean that I'm going to have a **lot** of these LINQ queries in my up-coming set of work so, if possible, I'd like to find a solution that allows me to use Anonymous Types.

Does anyone know of a solution or workaround for the error I'm getting?

Comment: `may be many different types that need to be passed to the method` then use `object` instead of the marker interface. I see no value in using a marker interface at this point

Comment: Doh. Let me go and try that.

Comment: @Jehof, if you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Jehof is right. you're trying to pass a generic class to a method that's supposed to receive an interface.