# Interface just as a "filter type"?

Tags: c#, interface

Maybe it's a silly question but I was wondering if is it a good practice to create an empty interface just as a "filter" type?

For example: Do some action only on objects that implement the required/certain interface?

Comment: That "some action" would still require reflection and type-casting. So it doesn't seem like an ideal way to accomplish anything.

Comment: Define the "action" in the interface and then it isn't empty! Call the action on anything that implements the interface.

Comment: There is one case when this is valid. This is when binding interface/empty abstract class to a property of `ContentControl` and swaping implementations at runtime

Comment: I guess it would be good to define "Do some action". There are manipulation that require access to certain properties of methods, so it is in this case not a good practice to have an empty interface.

Comment: One valid vase that comes to my mind is if you want to put different generic classes into the same collection like `List<iMyInterface> collection` and fill it with for example `class CarService : BaseService<Car>, MyInterface`, `class HouseService : BaseService<House>, MyInterface`, `class StuffService : BaseService<SomeotherStuff>, MyInterface`.

Comment: `if is it a good practice to create an empty interface just as a "filter" type?` Sure - I've used that many times before. 'Good practice' is of course hard to pin down, but I wouldn't say it is 'bad practice'.

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways than using a [Marker Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern), FXCop recommends [Avoid empty interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/ms182128(v=vs.80))

See these answers for more details;

- [Empty Interface usage - Is this a code smell?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43288)
- [Are empty interfaces code smell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552677/)

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct and it is what interfaces are for, but you have mentioned that:

> Do some action

which indicates you want to execute some method, and that is even better. In that case I'd suggest such interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
  void MyAction();
}
```

Then you can call `MyAction` on any object that implemnets the interface.

Obviously, `void` here can be changed to any type you want to return and you can use any arguments that fit your requirement :)

[More on interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface).

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are used to force something, Like every car has tires, dashboard, horn functionality . 
So this CarObject class will be inherited by all Car classes and the implementation of the functions in CarObject class will be forced to do in classes inheriting them. SO yes, it can be used as a filter and add functionality as needed.