# Are empty interfaces code smell when they used to add a constraint to a generic interface?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

It's already been covered in a few topics that empty interfaces that are used as markers where identification occurs at run time are [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552677) [smell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1040), but what about when you have something like this:

```
public interface IPropertyRetriever<out T>
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public T Retrieve();
}

public interface IComparablePropertyRetriever<out T> : IPropertyRetriever<T> where T : IComparable
{
}
```

In this example, although `IComparablePropertyRetriever<T>` is an empty interface, it does add a constraint to what `T` can be. Would something like this also be considered code smell?

**EDIT**

Ok so here is both how I'm using it and the use case.

I'm building an expression parser that consists of an expression, an operator and a constant, so I ended up with this:

```
public interface IOperator<out T>
{
    public IPropertyRetriever<T> LeftObjectRetriever { get; }
      
    public T RightObject { get; }

    public bool Compare();
}
```

`T` can only ever be one of 4 types: `string`, `bool?`, `long?` and `Version`

My operators are things like `StartsWith`, `GreaterThan`, `LowerEquals`, `Contains`...

Clearly some operators such as `StartsWith` and `Contains` only work on strings and that's pretty simple to do, I can just do this:

```
public class BeginsWith : IOperator<string>
{
    public BeginsWith(IPropertyRetriever<string> leftObjectRetriever, string rightObject)
    {
        LeftObjectRetriever = leftObjectRetriever;
        RightObject = rightObject;
    }

    public IPropertyRetriever<string> LeftObjectRetriever { get; }
        
    public string RightObject { get; }
        
    public bool Compare()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But others, such as `LowerThan` work on all other types, except string. And although I guess I could do something like this (which is ultimately what the `IComparablePropertyRetriever<T>` interface is doing)

```
public class LowerThan : IOperator<IComparable>
{
}
```

It still allows me to pass a `string` to `LowerThan` since string implements `IComparable`

By shifting the responsability to the classes implementing `IPropertyRetriever` (which I can control far more easily) I can instead do something like this:

```
public class FileVersionRetriever : IComparablePropertyRetriever<Version>
{
}
```

And implement `LowerThan` as follows:

```
public interface IComparableOperator : IOperator<IComparable>
{
    public new IComparablePropertyRetriever<IComparable> LeftObjectRetriever { get; }
}

public class LowerThan : IComparableOperator
{
}
```

And I guess now that I've explained that the whole question turned into something completely different which is how to implement this better xD

Comment: What does the constraint achieve if `T` is not being used in the definition?

Comment: The smell here is the use of a `property retriever` interface - what is this trying to achieve? As for the linked 10-year old question, things have changed since and *some* pattern matching cases require "marker" interfaces, at least until C# 10 introduces discriminated unions.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I don't follow your reasoning...

Comment: @InBetween It was more of a question than a statement. I'd be interested to know how this could be useful.

Comment: BTW `IComparablePropertyRetriever` in this case isn't a marker. It add some restrictions but omits important information. I suspect the entire design could be simplified a lot. If you want to "inject" some behavior to classes, you could use default interface member implementations for example. If  you want to create class that acts as a proxy, whose properties are loaded from a remote system or database, you could put the loading code in the interface's `Retrieve()` for example. This way you'd avoid inheriting from a base abstract class. Loading the *class*  on demand though, would be cleaner

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos mode info added

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay added more info